# When I try to run a video using openCV, the program automatically rotates the video

Tags: opencv

When I try to run a video using opencv, the video keeps rotating so that the wide side of the video is displayed on horizon. I wonder how I can set the original video to display correctly....

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2



cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/junsuk/Desktop/python/ch13/testbar.mp4')

if not cap.isOpened():
print('Video open failed!')
sys.exit()



tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('/Users/junsuk/Desktop/python/ch10/photo.jpg', frame)
if not ret:
    print('Frame read failed!')
sys.exit()
newdraw=cv2.imread('/Users/junsuk/Desktop/python/ch10/photo.jpg')
cv2.line(newdraw, (50, 50), (200, 50), (0, 0, 255), 5)
cv2.imwrite('/Users/junsuk/Desktop/python/ch10/photo.jpg', newdraw)

rc = cv2.selectROI('frame', frame)
print(rc)
tracker.init(frame, rc)


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print('Frame read failed!')
        sys.exit()

    ret, rc = tracker.update(frame)
rc = tuple([int(_) for _ in rc])
cv2.rectangle(frame, rc, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(25) == 45:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: camera sensor gives images in landscape format, so the images actually are correct. All kind of video players use the meta information (exif orientation values?) about camera rotation, to rotate the images on the fly. OpenCV doesnt do that automatically.

Comment: you try to get the VideoCapture property: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da161e0ba8e8fad2a34880e0fc6753a2b2 and depending on the value, rotate the image after capturing, if that information is supported on your opencv build.

Comment: I added my code, and I still can't solve this problem..

Comment: you were given a link to documentation. at least click on the link, read what's written there, and think about how it applies to the situation.